# Volume for HTML5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, volume

I tried to modify the volume of the video element with `element.volume = whatever`, where `whatever` is a value between 0 and 1. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I get no error in the console. I tried in both Firefox and Chrome.

I looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video and this should be the way.

I also looked at [HTML5 Video Tag Volume Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301435/html5-video-tag-volume-support) and tried the method in the accepted answer to see if the browser supports it. Using that method (second one) it seems to be supported.

Am I missing something? Is there a well known bug for this?

Comment: yes, this should be the way, what value has `whatever`?

Comment: volume should be a number between `0` and `1`, inclusive

Comment: `whatever` is a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Then can't repro, please add an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get your "element"? Maybe you should get the video element again before you assign the volume to see if works. I have been using html5 video player in the past 2 years and I didn't have any issue.

```
element = document.getElementById("VIDEO_ID");
element.volume = whatever;
```

Comment: Actually, Alex is right. I was getting the element from an angular directive, which is actually the jqlite wrapped element. Duh ... But ci_ has also a good point. First a comment should have been more appropriate. Plus Alex had just a lucky guess, I didn't offer enough information to see what was actually the issue.
Anyway, I voted both the answer and comment and many thanks.